# how to invoke IntelliJ InlineMethod action via code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm writing a refactoring plugin for IntelliJ and I'd like to call the action to `Inline method` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>).

Given I have the `PsiMethod` of the method to be inlined, what is the best approach ?

Should I somehow try to find and execute the inlining via the command id (and can I skip the dialog ?)

Or can I use something like `InlineMethodProcessor` manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it, you can do it like this:

```
new InlineMethodProcessor(project, psiMethod1, null, editor, false).run();
new InlineMethodProcessor(project, psiMethod2, null, editor, false).run();
```

Incidentally, now that I've done 2 refactorings, they result in 2 undo actions.

Is there a way to "wrap" them (and other things) into one undo action, I wonder?